# Ctrl+C on ListView recognises as "LButton | Shift Key"

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, hotkeys

How can I catch "ctrl+c" keys pressed on listview?

I'm trying like that

```
private void listviewLogger_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != listviewLogger) return;

    //if (e.Control && e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        CopySelectedValuesToClipboard();
}
```

but it shows me the combination of *LButton | Sift Key* when I press ctrl+C:
[image]

P.S.: have two languages installed in windows, system Win2012 R2

**Update1:** thank You for comment! If I log actions, I see this:

> e.KeyData: ControlKey
> e.KeyCode: ControlKey
> e.KeyData: C
> e.KeyCode: C

But still cannot catch this key sequence. Code:

```
private void listviewLogger_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != listviewLogger)
        return;

    Logger("e.KeyData: " + e.KeyData);
    Logger("e.KeyCode: " + e.KeyCode);
}
```

**Update2:**

Resolved like this. Don't ask my how :-D

```
if (((e.KeyData & Keys.ControlKey) != Keys.ControlKey) && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    CopyLogEntriesToClipboard();
```

**Update3:**

Previous works for **KeyUp** event. For **KeyDown** first code-snippet works

Comment: Well, you can't debug GUI code with breakpoints like that. It is breaking in with you having released the left mouse button and the shift key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to catch key down event (I've checked it on editor by holding Ctrl+C and switching to another up without relesing buttons).
Please try one more time your first construction. It is works for me!

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        Text = "got it";
}
```

Comment: Yes You are right! Seems to be something with KeyUp. I'll update the fost